# How to resolved Invalid Credential error in ANH for iOS?

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I've set up an `Azure Notification Hub` and I have gone through all the steps to implement `Push Notification` into my iOS app. The app has been working fine, receiving the push notifications just like it should. Then today I went to try and send a push from the `Azure Portal` and it failed.

It seems to be only iOS related though, as the devices that run my app in Android are receiving the `Push Notification` like they should. I know for a fact I have not changed anything in my code. But instead of getting the `Push Notification` like I should I now get the following message in Azure portal.

> The Push Notification System rejected the request because of an
>   Invalid Credential.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just resolved this issue. Just create new `APNS` certificates and add it to `Azure Portal` APNS settings. Now it works fine. But Why this is happened I don't understand that. If anyone have idea regarding this then please share it.

If any other solution then please share it here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a potential explanation to your problem.
When you configure APNS into an ANH (Azure Notification Hub), you have the choice between 2 approaches:

- Certificate
- Token

Of what I understood, you have used "certificate", and APNS certificate expires every year:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_certificate-based_connection_to_apns

So maybe, your certificate has expired, and when you created a new one, it has solved your issue.

The other approach with "Token", has the advantage of never expiring.

Regards,

Loic